# Setting same gtk/openbox theme in both 64 bit native and 32 bit chroot environment

Tags: arch-linux, openbox, theme, gtk3

I'm running Arch Linux and have setup a 32bit chroot environment inside a 64bit native install per [their wiki instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_bundled_32-bit_system_in_Arch64).

I've installed the Zukitwo and Zukitwo-Openbox themes via the [Arch Linux AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/), which install to `/usr/share/themes/Zukitwo`.

I'm setting my theme via `obconf` (for openbox) and `lxappearance` (for gtk apps). For some reason, when setting gtk theme with `lxappearance` in the 64bit native environment, my 32bit chroot apps default to the Raleigh theme (looks like Win 3.1). If I enter the chroot and use `lxappearance` to set the same theme (which I've installed in the chroot as well), the 64bit native environment applications switch to Raleigh theme.

Since this should just be making changes to, as far as I know, `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`, why might my theme not be consistent between the two environments?

Here is the script that starts the 32bit chroot at boot (removed stop case to minimize post length):

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=(/dev /dev/pts /dev/shm /tmp /home)

case $1 in
    start)
        for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
          mount -o bind $d /opt/arch32/$d
        done
        mount -t proc none /opt/arch32/proc
        mount -t sysfs none /opt/arch32/sys
        ;;

    stop) [... removed ...]
esac
```

`/home` gets mounted, so the two should just be bound in the chroot and they're sharing the same home directory, right? (Using `diff` on settings.ini in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini and /opt/arch32/home/username/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini reveals no differences.)

Comment: Commenting to bump... please let me know if you have any further questions as I'd really love to get this resolved and will provide any additional information required!

Comment: Looks like I can't answer my own question as I don't have enough rep on this site yet. Bottom line is I'm an idiot and didn't have *exactly* the same themes installed. I had a different Zukitwo/Zukitwo-ob theme installed in the chroot despite swearing that wasn't the case. Easiest way may be to just install to 64bit env and then copy to `/path/to/chroot/usr/share/themes/`. Then, as I thought, the .config, residing in `~/` should work just fine as the chroot will see the same theme in `/usr/share/themes`. Silly, silly, silly.